# Multiple custom markers import in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I use Leaflet to present some points on map. However, I want to place different marker depending on some parameters. 
The question is: is it possible to import in React whole directory of my custom markers (.png files)? 
Currently it looks like this:

```
import icon from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png';
```

And then

```
render() {
  const position = [54.40, 18.60];
  let DefaultIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: icon,
  shadowUrl: iconShadow,
  iconSize: [24, 36],
  iconAnchor: [12, 36],
  popupAnchor: [0, -25]
});
```

So for one marker there's one import at the top.

Say I want to import few icons, so do I have to import every single `.png` file separately at the top of my react component? Or is there a way to just import a directory and then place only path to appropriate icon file?

Comment: I guess you use webpack to build your project? In that case, it seems to me your question and potential solution involve webpack, and not really react nor Leaflet. You should add the webpack tag and state it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that matter a webpack feature called [dynamic require](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression) could be utilized, for example with *expression*:

```
const icon = L.icon({
     iconUrl: require(`../public/custom-icons/${item.iconName}`),
});
```

icons images dynamically get loaded from `/public/custom-icons/` folder and included in bundle

Example

```
const MapExample = () => {
  const data = [
    { position: { lat: -33.8478796, lng: 150.7918932 }, title: "Sydney", "iconName" : "leaf-red.png" },
    { position: { lat: -31.954654, lng: 115.8399823 }, title: "Perth ", "iconName" : "leaf-green.png" }
  ];

  return (
    <Map center={{ lat: -24.9929159, lng: 115.2297986 }} zoom={4}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      {data.map((item, idx) => {
        const icon = L.icon({
          iconUrl: require(`../public/custom-icons/${item.iconName}`),
          iconSize: [24, 36],
          iconAnchor: [12, 36],
          popupAnchor: [0, -25]
        });

        return (
          <Marker key={idx} icon={icon} position={item.position}>
            <Popup>{item.title}</Popup>
          </Marker>
        );
      })}
    </Map>
  );
};
```

Here is [a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/2o4ry4qr80)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this kinda thing:

```
  if ( feature.properties.name === "NONE") {
    var shadow = "Project/data/images/NONE.png";
  } else {
    var shadow = "Project/data/images/shadow.png";
  }

  var flag = L.icon({
    shadowUrl: shadow,
    iconUrl: `Project/data/images/${feature.properties.name }.png`,
```